# Can't find ~/.vim/bundle directory on Mac

Tags: macos, vim, youcompleteme

I am trying to install YouCompleteMe on Mac and following the procedure, I am not able to locate `~/.vim/bundle`. I can locate `.vim` in my home folder but there is no directory `bundle` inside it.

I am following this link https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/README.md#installation to install YouCompleteMe.

Answer (score 1):

if it doesn't exists it is safe to create it

Answer (score 0):

You first need to install [vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) Plugin Manager that will create this folder for you.